# Error con el sdk de facebook al iniciar sesion

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema al intentar iniciar sesion en mi aplicacion con facebook me muestra el siguiente mensaje

```
Inicio de sesión no seguro bloqueado: No puedes obtener un token de acceso ni iniciar sesión en esta aplicación desde una página no segura. Intenta volver a cargar la página como https://
```

y como estoy desarrollando la web desde mi local debería ser un error de configuración, si alguno sabe el motivo de ese mensaje

Comment: Por lo que dice el mensaje, tu dominio local debe ser https para poder obtener el token ej. `https://www.tudominiolocal.cl`

Answer (score -1):

In Django: To use HTTPS in your website, add the following in your project's settings.py file:

```
# Force https redirect
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
# Force HTTPS in the final URIs
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True
```

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Los posts deben está en español, debes traducir tu respuesta